# unable to create schema in hbase using phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

```
I am using Phoenix verion :4.10.0-HBase-1.2

I am getting below error while creating new schema:
```

> Inconsistent namespace mapping properites.. Ensure that config
>       phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled is consitent on client and
>       server.

```
What does mean by ensure on client and server ??  
What changes i need to do ??
```

hbase-site.xml
    ------------------------
      `<property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
 </property>`

> Java code :
>       ----------------
>       Connection connection = setupDbConnection();
>       statement statement = connection.createStatement();
>       int status = statement.executeUpdate("CREATE SCHEMA test");
>       connection.commit();

```
please give me any suggestions..
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your setupDbConnection(); method to have the property set like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();      
properties.setProperty("phoenix.schema.mapSystemTablesToNamespace", "true");        
properties.setProperty("phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled", "true");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:...:/hbase", properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue occurs even after setting `phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled` to `true` make sure you have hbase conf folder on classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Set property `phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled` as `consitent` in `hbase-site.xml`